# How to invoke ballerina service in windows cmd

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, ballerina

I'm running my services in ballerina composer, then I'm using **Windows cmd** to invoke the service using the `curl` but `cmd` is complaining that `curl` is not a recognized command.

How could I do it in `cmd`?

Please help.

Comment: Did you try invoking the service with integrated "try it" tool in ballerina composer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your service file, here it is `hello_service.bal`.

---

```
import ballerina/http;

endpoint http:Listener listener {
    port:9090
};

service<http:Service> hello bind listener {
    sayHello (endpoint caller, http:Request request) {

        http:Response response = new;

        response.setTextPayload("Hello World!\n");

        _ = caller -> respond(response);
    }
}
```

---

2. Run it on cmd. `ballerina run hello_service.bal`

---

3. Make a new `main.bal` file.

---

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;
import ballerina/io;

endpoint http:Client clientEndpoint {
    url: "http://localhost:9090"
};

function main(string... args) {
    // Send a GET request to the Hello World service endpoint.
    var response = clientEndpoint->get("/hello/sayHello");

    match response {
        http:Response resp => {
            io:println(resp.getTextPayload());
        }
        error err => {
            log:printError(err.message, err = err);
        }
    }
}
```

---

4. `ballerina run main.bal`.

---

5. You can see the result as `Hello World!` on cmd now.

---

Comment: This would be ideal way if you want to learn ballerina!. By writing your own client.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use cURL to invoke Ballerina HTTP services. You can use the HTTP client you normally use (e.g., [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)). If you really want to, you can install cURL in Windows as well: https://curl.haxx.se/download.html.